# if database is not ready, then can we run the hibernate code on server?

Tags: hibernate

I am using MySQL workbench,  hibernate 3.  I am trying to run the code on tomcat server.  Is it possible to do that?

Comment: If you want to know if it is possible you can try google. If you need help implementing it try telling us what you have tried.

Comment: yes, I got solution.  thanks for reply.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck =)